# “Child already has a parent, it must be removed first” ao enviar novo objeto para reducer

Tags: react, redux

Possuo uma tabela onde desejo ordenar seus dados.

A tabela é copulada através dos valores deste `useSelector()`

```
const users = useSelector(state => state.userStates.users)
```

Quando o usuário clica em uma das colunas da tabela, eu mando para a função `sortBy()` a chave que vou ordenar:

```
<TableCell onClick={() => sortBy('login')}>Email</TableCell>
```

E então minha função realiza a ordenação:

```
const sortBy = (key) => {
    // If is using a field different by the last, starts ordering in asc
    if (key !== orderingField) {
        setOrderingStatus('asc')
        setOrderingField(key)
    // Reverte a ordenação
    } else { 
        if (orderingStatus === 'asc') {
            setOrderingStatus('desc')
        } else {
            setOrderingStatus('asc')
        }
    }
    let copyUsers = {}
    copyUsers.data = [...users] // make a copy of the obj
    copyUsers.lastPage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lastPage)) // copy of the last page 
    copyUsers.data.sort(compareValues(orderingField, orderingStatus)) // make the sort)
    dispatch(userActions.setUserList(copyUsers))
}

export default function compareValues(key, order = 'asc') {
    return function innerSort(a, b) {
      if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // property doesn't exist on either object
        return 0;
      }

      const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string')
        ? a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
      const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string')
        ? b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

      let comparison = 0;
      if (varA > varB) {
        comparison = 1;
      } else if (varA < varB) {
        comparison = -1;
      }
      return (
        (order === 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
      );
    };
}
```

Os dados estão sendo ordenados corretamente através dessa função, porém, quando realizo o `dispatch()` desse objeto eu recebo vários erros:

> Child already has a parent, it must be removed first.
>   nbind.js:9812 Uncaught abort() at Error

Eu acredito que seja algo na cópia do objeto users que está o problema, porém ainda não consegui entender o que está havendo e como solucionar.

```
copyUsers.data = [...users] // Funciona
copyUsers.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users)) // Da o erro
copyUsers.data = [...users] // Da o erro
```

Comment: O código chama na pesquisa o `dispatch`, bem estranho.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic pelo que debuguei, se eu mando o objeto copyUsers.data = [...users] copiado dessa forma, ele da esse erro, o mesmo ocorre se eu tentar com JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) e outros métodos que copia o objeto. Eu tive que passar o objeto sem cópia, e então funcionou.

Comment: Eu realmente gostaria de entender o porque isso está acontecendo.

Comment: `copyUsers.data = [...users] // make a copy of the obj`, não deveria ser `copyUsers.data = {...users]}// make a copy of the obj`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acho que não, porque o objeto users é um array, se eu colocar {...users} ele coloca o meu users dentro de outro objeto, quando eu printo console.log(copyUsers.data) eu tenho o array de objetos conforme esperado, ele até sorteia, mas quando mando pro reducer ele da esse erro.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o problema seja que ao copiar os objetos, você não está criando novos objetos, mas criando um novo array com referências pros mesmos objetos que estavam no antigo array `users`.

Tente usar algo como `copyUsers.data = users.map(user => ({...user}))` para realmente fazer uma cópia dos objetos.

Answer (score -4):

Eu não estou muito dentro do assunto de redux, mas supostamente o erro que te ocorre não é porque no teu HTML estás a chamar um objecto na função de click?

O teu código está assim:

```
<TableCell onClick={() => sortBy('login')}>Email</TableCell>
```

e não deveria ser algo assim do género?

```
<TableCell onClick="sortBy('login')">Email</TableCell>
```

Posso estar errado, mas espero conseguir ajudar.

Comment: Isso não é HTML. É JSX, a propriedade `onClick` (`prop`) está válida. Não creio que isso irá responder à pergunta...

Comment: A chamada da função está sendo feita normalmente. Não é esse o problema